# ¿como cambiar etiquetas de html al mismo tiempo vscode?

Tags: html5, vscode

en vscode como puedo cambiar la etiqueta de apertura y cierre al mismo tiempo, en este caso con un h1 , he visto que cambian la de apertrua y automaticamente o con un atajo se cambia la de cierre. pero no he podido

```
<h1> noticias </h1>
```

cambiando el primer h1 de apertura por h2 se cambia el de cierre solo o con un atajo.

```
<h2> noticias </h2>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! vs code no hace nada por si mismo.. vas a necesitar un plugin que lo haga...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega `"editor.linkedEditing": true` en tu `settings.json` y cambian ambas etiquetas al mismo tiempo cuando las editas. Alternativamente podrías usar [Auto Rename Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag) pero ya no es recomendable ya que `vscode` trae esto de manera nativa desde la [version 1.52](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52). Para más detalles checa [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vv7G-qgUTQ).

Comment: gracias funciono perfecto ! :)